# MySql varchar length for emojis on Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, varchar, utf8mb4, sequelpro

I'm using MySql version 5.6.46 on Linux.
I have a column  `name  varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` and `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4`.

When I tried to insert some data into the table. I find that,

> for `a` (1 byte in utf8), it can store 50 maximum.

> for `爱` (3 bytes in utf8, Chinese character love), it can store 50 maximum.

> for  (4 bytes in utf8, hex `F09F9881`), it can store 25 maximum.

This confuses me. Why Mysql is not treating one emoji as one character? If Mysql does the byte-count limit and improperly uses 3-byte-per-character, I'm expecting it can store 50*3/4=37. How on earth Mysql do the restriction?

----------UPDATE-------------

Thanks to your response, I figure it out. I am on MacOS X and I was using  `Sequel Pro 1.1.2`. When I edit table content in the UI of the software, the maximum is 25 emoji and it toasts warning `maximum text length is set to 50`

Then I tried the raw hex approach on the server `set name = X'F09F9881...F09F9881'` and it can hold 50 emojis perfectly.

So this is a Sequel Pro issue. I will add `Sequel Pro` tag to this question. Hope this will help people who met the same issue. Thanks

Comment: It's possibly a bug/limitation because it works correctly starting on [MySQL/8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=caee3b14e9ac7e09c057bd769e2756c7).

Comment: Allows 50 but not 51  on MySQL5.7.28

Comment: @RiggsFolly Funny. Not on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=caee3b14e9ac7e09c057bd769e2756c7) :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am on Windows, could that be making a difference? Just tried it on MySQL 5.6.46 and I can store 50 but not 51  on there also

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fe0a240e6982e95b3f6aa1dc8f12128b - the difference is obvious. May compare with 5.7... or MariaDB.

Comment: There is something wrong with dbfiddle.uk - `char_length()` returns a wrong result. Even for latin (`char_length('é')`). Nothing like that on [dg-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/crcLPPc8TJa3NedBCSV9Wh/0)

Comment: @matrix, Please post your system specs (including OS with exact version) and post a result of `CHAR_LENGTH`.

Comment: Seems like the same versions of MySQL on Linux and Windows give very different results ??

Comment: Nope. Works for me on debian and windows the same. MySQL aswell as MariaDB. Only that doesn't work is dbfiddle.uk. Didn't test any 5.6 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No arithmetic needed.

```
varchar(50)
```

Holds 50 *characters* of any type.  This will occupy up to 202 *bytes* (4 * 50 + 2 for a hidden length field).

To debug your situation, please provide:

```
SELECT VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';

SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...  -- to show what was stored.
```

Comment: @matrix - `ucs2` / `utf16` woiuld take 2 bytes per emoji.  Check the settings in sequel pro.  `utf-8`/`utf8mb4` is the only reasonable charset to use these days.